# How do I send the response from an async tornado post request to render on an html template?

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, asynchronous, response, tornado

I'm trying to get a handle on using `tornado`'s async capabilities.  So far I've only been marginally successful. I'm using a modified version of what I found [here](https://gist.github.com/FZambia/5756470) to assists with my async. Perhaps it's not the best way, you tell me what you think or if there is a better way.  Here is the `subprocess_helper.py` file that I use to help with my async request.

```
import tornado.process
import subprocess
import logging

from tornado.gen import Task, Return, coroutine
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

STREAM = tornado.process.Subprocess.STREAM
@coroutine
def call_subprocess(cmd, stdin_data=None, stdin_async=False):
  """
  Wrapper around subprocess call using Tornado's Subprocess class.
  """
  stdin = STREAM if stdin_async else subprocess.PIPE

  sub_process = tornado.process.Subprocess(
      cmd, stdin=stdin, stdout=STREAM, stderr=STREAM
  )

  if stdin_data:
      if stdin_async:
          yield Task(sub_process.stdin.write, stdin_data)
      else:
          sub_process.stdin.write(stdin_data)

  if stdin_async or stdin_data:
      sub_process.stdin.close()

  result, error = yield [
      Task(sub_process.stdout.read_until_close),
      Task(sub_process.stderr.read_until_close)
  ]

  raise Return((result, error))


def on_timeout():
  logging.info("timeout")
  #IOLoop.instance().stop()
  #IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

This is the view:

```
import app.basic
import tornado.web
import time
import os
import shlex

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.gen import coroutine

#from datetime import datetime
from lib import subprocess_helper
from lib import ad_sizesdb, sitesdb, audit_notesdb


class Repull(app.basic.BaseHandler):
  @tornado.web.authenticated
  def get(self):
   if self.get_secure_cookie("account_type") not in ['admin']:
     self.redirect('/')
   else:
     slug = self.get_argument('slug','')
     size = self.get_argument('ad_size', '')

     ad_sizes = ad_sizesdb.get_ad_sizes()
     slugs = sitesdb.get_all_slugs()
     self.render('admin_tools/repull.html', active_section='repull_invocation', ad_sizes=ad_sizes, slug=slug, slugs=slugs, size=size, expand_tools=True)

  @tornado.web.authenticated
  @coroutine
  def post(self):
    slug = self.get_argument('slug','')
    size = self.get_argument('ad_size', '')
    if slug != '' and size != '':
      seconds_to_wait = 300
      deadline = time.time() + seconds_to_wait
      IOLoop.instance().add_timeout(deadline, subprocess_helper.on_timeout)

      file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)).replace('app', 'scripts/pull_invocation_codes.py'))
      #cmd = shlex.split('python {0} "{1}" "adtech" "{2}"'.format(file_path, slug, size))
      cmd = 'ls'
      result, error = yield subprocess_helper.call_subprocess(cmd, stdin_async=True)
    
      if result != '':
        msg = 'invocation code for {0}_{1} pulled'.format(slug, size)
        #log_audit_note(msg)
        self.api_response(msg)
      else:
        msg = 'invocation for {0}_{1} not pull something happened'.format(slug, size)
        #log_audit_note(msg)
        self.api_response(msg)
    else:
      self.error(400, 'slug or ad size blank')
    #self.redirect('/admin/admin_tools/repull??ad_size={0}&slug={1}'.format(size, slug))
```

The template

```
{% set active_section = 'admin_tools' %}
{% extends ../admin.html %}

{% block middle_content %}
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <form name="form" action="/admin/admin_tools/repull" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Ad Size</label>
        <select id="ad_size" name="ad_size" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width:100%;">
          <option value=""></option>
          {% for size in ad_sizes %}
            <option value='{{size['size']}}' {% if size['size'] == size %} selected {% end %}>{{size['size']}}</option>
          {% end %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Slugs</label>
        <select id="slug" name="slug" data-init-plugin="select2" style="width:100%;">
          <option value=""></option>
          {% for s in slugs %}
            <option value='{{s['slug']}}' {% if s['slug'] == slug %} selected {% end %}>{{s['slug']}}</option>
          {% end %}
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pull Adtech Invocation Code</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div>Notes:</div>
    <div id="notes"></div>
  </div>
{% end %}

{% block javascript %}
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(){
      $('#notes').html('Running for invocation for ' + slug + '_' + adsize);
      $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) { 
        $('#notes').html(data['data']); 
        return false; 
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
{% end %}
```

So a little background. The reason why I need this call to be async is because the post request is triggering another file which uses selenium to help with automations.  Some things I don't really understand and want help with include the use of `IOLoop.instance().stop()` the link above uses it to help with the timeout and later it's how in the post call is ended. I commented it out because if I don't the tornado thread is terminated at the end of the post.  Which I suppose makes sense given the name of the method I'm calling... Overall I want to be able to run the post async and get some kind of response when it's done so that I can trigger some king of visual on the template so that the user has some kind of clue stuff is happened/completed/failed.  What I'm I doing wrong?  How can I fix it?  If this is not the best approach what is?

**UPDATES**:  I added the template, after thinking about it I suppose what I want is the response to render correctly on the template. I added an image of what i'm correctly getting, which is not what I except.  That message is render on a blank page, but if you take a look at the html template, when I receive the response data I want to jquery inject into a div instead. I'm returning false in the jQuery[image]

Comment: The code looks decent to me; what exactly are you expecting and what is happening instead? You definitely don't want to use `IOLoop.stop()` anywhere; that's for shutting down the whole server and has no place in a regular request. Do you mean perhaps to start the subprocess in the POST, send a response to the client, and then get the result of the subprocess in some later request?

Comment: @BenDarnell I've made some updates to the post after reading your comment.  Adding some clarification, when the subprocess yields a result I want to send/write an api response back.. It works except that when I sent the data it returns a blank page with the json response.  I want to jQuery to receive the response and inject the response into a div instead.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're looking for now. Unfortunately I don't know enough javascript/jquery to help you with it. The server side is fine; it's something about how you're making the request from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was making multiple post I had to prevent default

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var slug = $('#slug').val();
      var adsize = $('#ad_size').val();
      if((slug && adsize) != ''){
        $('#notes').html('Running for invocation for ' + slug + '_' + adsize + ' if you don\'t want to wait for the reponse you can check the audit notes later');
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) { 
          $('#notes').html(data['data']); 
          return false; 
        });
      }
    });
```